# What is the value of the convergent series $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (e^{-4n}-e^{-4(n-1)})$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Consider the series 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  (e^{-4n}-e^{-4(n-1)}).
$$ 
I know the series must converge but, what test should I employ to find the value of the series?

**Attempt**:
I have tried using the integral test, which gives a value of 3/2, but it is incorrect.

The following is the original problem:

> [image]

Comment: This is a telescoping series.  Try writing out the first few terms to see the cancellations.  Alternatively you can just factor out $e^{-4n}$ and you get a standard geometric sum.

Comment: I assume you know how to evaluate $A\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} r^n$.

Comment: Assuming the terms of the series are monotonic, the only thing you can get out of the integral test is whether the sum converges. You cannot compute the value of the series this way.

Answer (score 2):

This series converges. Here is the reason:$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  e^{-4n}-e^{-4(n+1)}{=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  e^{-4n}-e^{-4n}e^{-4}\\=(1-e^{-4})\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-4n}\\=(1-e^{-4}){e^{-4}\over 1-e^{-4}}\\=e^{-4}}$$

Answer (score 1):

The partial sums are $e^{-4}-e^{-4(n+1)}$ by induction, making the limit $e^{-4}$.

Comment: Exploiting the telescoping series is a much more expedient way forward.

Answer (score 0):

Split the sum$$\begin{align*}\sum\limits_{n\geq1}\left[e^{-4n}-e^{-4(n-1)}\right] & =\sum\limits_{n\geq1}e^{-4n}-\sum\limits_{n\geq1}e^{-4(n-1)}\\ & =e^{-4}\sum\limits_{n\geq0}e^{-4n}-\sum\limits_{n\geq0}e^{-4n}\\ & =\left(e^{-4}-1\right)\sum\limits_{n\geq0}e^{-4n}\end{align*}$$The infinite sum converges by the infinite geometric sequence which converges for $|x|<1$.$$\sum\limits_{n\geq0}x^n=\frac 1{1-x}$$It can be shown that $e^{-4}<1$, meaning the sum converges.